# JavaFX TableView doesn't update values

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am working on a personal project, my application "manages" the data for a car dealership. There is menus where you can add cars to the garage and some others where you can sell a car. The application is for the employees, the system that they use to storage their sales, basically. The data storing is made by an offline method (that's not the source of problem, that's working perfectly). The problem is in the method that removes a car from the list, I believe. To show to java when the TableView needs to be updated I inserted a listener in a static variable that is publicy acessible, when this variable becomes true the table updates, in theory.

```
NEEDS_DATA_UPDATE.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

        if(newValue){

            try {
                tableView.getItems().clear();
                tableView.setItems(DataStorageService.carsStoraged());
                tableView.refresh();
                
                NEEDS_DATA_UPDATE.set(false);
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
```

As seen in this gif: https://gph.is/g/EGnGANM , the table only really updates when I press "remove" button again, even though `tableView.getItems().size()` returns the correct value right after the line `tableView.setItems(DataStorageService.carsStoraged());` (Checked in debug function of IDE). That is, even with the table containing the correct items, the GUI doesn't show the correct information.

Here is the controller class:

```
package garage;

import entities.Car;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import main.Main;
import services.DataStorageService;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class GarageController implements Initializable {

    public static SimpleBooleanProperty NEEDS_DATA_UPDATE = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    @FXML
    public Button exitButton;
    public Button insertButton;
    public Button removeButton;
    public Button backButton;
    public TableView<Car> tableView;
    public TableColumn<Car, String> brand;
    public TableColumn<Car, String> model;
    public TableColumn<Car, Double> value;
    public TableColumn<Car, Integer> mileage;

    @FXML
    public void onActionExitButton(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        Stage stage = (Stage) exitButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    public void onActionInsertButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Stage popup = new Stage();
        popup.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("../garage/newCar_scene.fxml"))));
        popup.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        popup.setX(380);
        popup.setY(260);
        popup.show();
    }

    public void onActionRemoveButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {

        try {
            DataStorageService.removeCarFromFile(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            Main.showInvalidEntryPopUp();
        }
        finally{
            NEEDS_DATA_UPDATE.set(true);
        }


    }

    public void onActionBackButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Main.enterMain((Stage) exitButton.getScene().getWindow());
    }

    public void updateTable() throws IOException{

    
        tableView.setItems(DataStorageService.carsStoraged());
        tableView.refresh();
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        brand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Brand"));
        model.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Model"));
        value.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Value"));
        mileage.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Mileage"));


        NEEDS_DATA_UPDATE.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if(newValue){

                try {

                    updateTable();
                    NEEDS_DATA_UPDATE.set(false);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });

        NEEDS_DATA_UPDATE.set(true);
    }
}
```

If the error can not be found(I admit, stackoverflow is my last option, I already do everything that my knowledgment permits), how can I rewrite this functionality?

Comment: [mcve] please .. unrelated: static scope is the wrong tool, (nearly) always but certainly here. And make certain you understand the mechanics of a) tableView updates (setup correctly, it will happen automagically) b) fxml (public fields/methods don't need the fxml annotation, or the other way round: if the annotation is needed, every single field has to be annotated)

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? Does your listener really gets called?

Comment: yet another don't: calling refresh is wrong (also nearly always but certainly here) - if seems to be required, there's something wrong with the setup)

Comment: kleopatra, I swear that if I know what is the problem I certainly would put an reproducible example but, as I say in the post, I only suppose _where_ it is. Second point, the static scope, why it is a wrong tool? If it really is, can you tell me the right tool? Regarding the table view mechanics, I understand them, all the others table views in the program works except that one, I believe it's a logic error.

Comment: mayamar, yes it is, every time that NEEDS_TABLE_UPDATE becomes true the listener's code is executed

Comment: kleopatra, the refresh method called is pure despair, I see other posts about table view update recommending this but sincerely it doesn't change anything in the results. It was just I try, maybe I should delete that line

Comment: `catch (NullPointerException e)` looks very suspicious.  No part of your code should ever cause a NullPointerException under any circumstances.  If you are getting a NullPointerException, you should fix the code rather than catching that exception.  Catching it may be causing your application to try to proceed using things which are not properly working.

Comment: I wish this was the problem but the `tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` can cause a NullPointerException if there's not selected item, in other words, if I don't select an item before press "remove" button

Comment: Don't use `try`-`catch` for regular logic. If a value might allowably be null, just do a null check. And as requested, provide a [mre]. Start from scratch and build up just enough to reproduce the problem in a complete example you can post here.

Comment: the referenced help page explains how to nail at least the location of a problem: either by divide-and-conquer - remove chunks from the code until it contains nothing but the offending lines or write something from scratch, until the same result. No way around, that's common trouble-shooting strategy. Often you'll find the solution yourself while doing it, if not you respect the helpers' resources in not forcing them to wade through tons of unrelated stuff ..

Comment: The implementation of `onActionRemoveButton(...)` should really just be: `Car selected = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();` `if (selected != null) { DataStorageService.removeCarFromFile(selected); tableView.getItems().remove(selected); }`. That's it: there's no need to reload the data from the database; just remove the item from the table's items list. If that doesn't work, something else is wrong with code you haven't posted in the question.

Comment: James_D your different implementation works, I really appreciate your help. I still do not know what's was the problem (even with 5 days of debug, yes it went on all this time, trust me) but it was certainly in that "listener workaround"/inexperience . As the Japaneses say, arigatou!